# strncat _emulations_ multiple calls ignore changed n?

Tags: c++

For self-study, here there are my 2 version of `strncat` (one with pointer+offset notation and one array version):

```
// 08_38.cpp                                                                    
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

char * strncatPtr(char * a, char * b, size_t n);
char * strncatArr(char * a, char * b, size_t n);

int main (void) {

   char string1[20] = "foobarqwerty";
   char string2[20] = "asd";

   // strncat                                                                   
   std::cout << "-----------------------" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "--------STRNCAT--------" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "-----------------------" << std::endl;
   std::cout << strncat(string2, string1, 6) << std::endl;
   std::cout << strcpy(string2, "asd") << std::endl;

   std::cout << strncatPtr(string2, string1, 4) << std::endl;
   std::cout << strcpy(string2, "asd") << std::endl;

   std::cout << strncatArr(string2, string1, 3) << std::endl;
   std::cout << strcpy(string2, "asd") << std::endl;

   return 0;
}

// ------------------------------------                                         
char * strncatPtr(char * a, char * b, size_t n){
   unsigned int i = 0;
   // go to the end;                                                            
   for(; *(a+i) != '\0'; i++);
   // and start copying                                                         
   for(unsigned int j = 0;
       ((*(a+i+j) = *(b+j)) != '\0') && (j < n-1);
       j++);
   return a;
}

char * strncatArr(char * a, char * b, size_t n){
   unsigned int i = 0;
   // go to the end;                                                            
   for(; a[i] != '\0'; i++);
   // and start copying                                                         
   for(unsigned int j = 0;
       ((a[i+j] = b[j]) != '\0') && (j < n-1);
       j++);
   return a;
}
```

I don't get why when i test them it considers size = 6 for every function call

```
-----------------------
--------STRNCAT--------
-----------------------
asdfoobar
asd
asdfoobar
asd
asdfoobar
asd
```

but if i test them separately, by commenting 2 different calls each time, they works fine... could you please enlighten me?

Comment: You do not terminate the destination in your functions, which will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when printing the strings.

Comment: Also, technically there's no difference between the two variants. `a[X]` is equivalent to `*(a + X)`, and the compiler will probably generate the same code for both functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, yes doing both versions was required by the exercise

Comment: Note also that your prototypes are incorrect if these functions are meant to emulate `strncat` - the second parameter should be `const char *`. Furthermore `strncat` is part of the standard C library, so your question should probably be tagged as C rather than C++.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of chars copied is less then the length of the string being concatenated then you are not adding a null-terminator to indicate the end of the string.